# real time java - how to apply multiple runs

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, real-time

I am working on real time java to implement a sensor network simulation. My simulation works but the problem is that I want to do some sensitivity analysis so I need to run the simulation multiple times, one after each other. After the first iteration I am not able to get any results due to suspends and activating or resetting them is was a bit problematic. So here is the code:

```
class Response_Time extends SimulationProcess{

/*static Random seed ;

public Response_Time(Random seeds) {
    seed= new Random (seeds);
}*/


public static void main(String[] args){

    for(int i=0;i<5; i++)
    {

    Response_Time exp = new Response_Time();
    exp.await();

    }

}


public void run(){



    System.out.println("Creating components...");
    Mesh2DSensorNetwork sn = new Mesh2DSensorNetwork(7,7);
    Task_Generator tg = new Task_Generator(sn);     
    emiission ee = new emiission(sn);
    DataCollection dc = new DataCollection(sn, tg);


    try {

        tg.Activate();
        ee.Activate();
        dc.Activate();
        sn.Activate();
        Scheduler.startSimulation();
        System.out.println("Simulation started... "+CurrentTime());
        Hold(576000);
        System.out.println("Simulation stopped... "+CurrentTime());
        Scheduler.stopSimulation();
        tg.terminate();
        ee.terminate();
        dc.terminate();
        sn.terminate();
        SimulationProcess.mainResume();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}


public void await ()
{
    this.Resume();
    //SimulationProcess.mainSuspend();
}

}
```

Comment: without knowing how SimulationProcess is coded, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: I am using a simulation library called JavaSim and in particular SimulationProcess is a class defined as

Comment: you have a link?  JavaSim has lots of hits on google...

Comment: [link](https://github.com/nmcl/JavaSim/tree/master/src/main/java/org/javasim)

Comment: I tried to use Runnable but either I could not implement it properly, or it is not possible to apply something like `System.out.println("numera" + i);
    Runnable m = new Response_Time();
    Thread t = new Thread(m);
    t.start();`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `Scheduler.reset()` to restart a simulation.  You also may need to call `SimulationProcess.finalize()` on the current process to remove it from the current collection of process (this project has some ugly use of static/global members).

Comment: I tried it as well, but never breaks the do while loop... What do you think about using a runnable

Comment: @user1638745 - quite frankly, how to use the library correctly is non-obvious.  i'd look for some documentation.

Comment: @user1638745 - which do while loop (there are 2 in the reset method)?

Comment: Problem is that when the simulation is over, it never returns to main thread because SimualtionProcess.mainSuspend () never unlocks the thread even after SimulationProcess.mainResume()

Comment: @user1638745 - did you try calling `this.terminate()`?

Comment: first one let me say. never goes out from `} while (!finished);`

  Scheduler.SimulatedTime = 0.0;
  Scheduler._simulationReset = false;
 }`

Comment: documentation is no longer online, but I have a user manual as pdf. there is one example about reparations and it has the code as: `public class Arrivals extends SimulationProcess
{
public void run ()
{
for (;;)
{
try
{
for (;;)
{
Customer c = new Customer();
queue.insert(c);
Hold(20.0);
}
}
catch (RestartException e)
{
}
}
}
}; ` can you suggest anything now??